# How to highlight active links in ASP.net / Razor View?

Tags: asp.net, razor, highlight

I just learn Asp.net.

How can one highlight in ASP.net active links (on which one is located) at the _Loayout.cshtml? I have not found possibility or example.

I just want to highlight automaticly the link "Config" if user is at this Controller + Action:

```html
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Config">Config</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Is this not possible?

Thanks a lot
Karsten

Comment: That seems like the best solution I was able to identify:
http://www.sweet-web-design.com/wordpress/how-to-add-active-class-to-menu-tab-in-asp-net-mvc/2954/